# Too Many Arguments

Tags: arguments

I want to add at the end of this statement `if(al2="", today()-ak2,"not enough info to calc)`, but I am getting a "too many arguments" message. Can anyone help me? I think that this may be a parentheses issue:

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR(AI2="",AH2=""),0,IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("lcl",BG2),0)=0,IF(BR2<>"","",IF(OR(IFERROR(SEARCH("port of ",E2),0)<>0,IFERROR(SEARCH("Dgf elp ",E2),0)<>0,IFERROR(SEARCH("energy",E2),0)<>0,IFERROR(SEARCH("silt ",E2),0)<>0,IFERROR(SEARCH("Delivered to ei ",E2),0)<>0,IFERROR(SEARCH({"Delivered","Confirmed","Appt","Completed","Ramp"},E2),0)<>0),IF(AW2<>"",IF(BF2<>"",BF2-AW2,TODAY()-AW2),IF(AQ2<>"",IF(BF2<>"",BF2-AQ2,TODAY()-AQ2),IF(AT2<>"",IF(BF2<>"",BF2-AT2,TODAY()-AT2),IF(BF2<>"",BF2-AL2,TODAY()-AL2)))),"")),"LCL")),0)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Peter .. thanks .. needs to be added at the end of the statement. Where you see the condition - IF(BF2<>"",BF2-AT2,TODAY()-AT2),IF(BF2<>"",BF2-AL2,TODAY()-AL2),if(al2="",today()-ak2,"not enough info to calc)))))),"")),"LCL")),0

Comment: basically if al2="", then take today()-ak2. If those conditions are not met, the not enough info

Comment: So, as I see it this is a complex formula getting out of hand. I suggest to install a capable text editor and save the formula as TEXT in a file with extension .BAS - by this you get the help of the parenthese matching of the editor. (e.g. Kate, Notepad++, ...). Note though: My checking in Kate revealed no faults; so it might just be that your formula is so long that Excel simply isn't capable to evaluate it.

Comment: doesn't work when I add the last piece if(al2="",today()-ak2,"not enough info to calc)))))),"")),"LCL")),0) ..so I still get the error ...too many arguments

Comment: Please [edit] and state explicitly: is this for Excel? or what? A proper tag would also be useful.